# Show a list of Posts in a different URL

Tags: python, django

Django Blog APP comes with an out of the box **index.html** where it shows a list of all posts.

I need to show this list in a new URL, when I somply copy the html code from **index.html** and paste onto **planoacao.html** it doesn´t show anything.

This is the index.html:

```
 {% for post in post_list %}
                <div class="card mb-4" style="width: 18rem; ">
                    {% if post.get_finalizado_display  == 'Não' %}
                    <!--<p class="card-text text-muted h6"> NOK </p>-->
                    <div class="card-body" style="background-color:#FF0909;">
                    {% else %}
                    <!--<p class="card-text text-muted h6"> ok </p>-->
                    <div class="card-body">
                    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is my views.py:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post

class PostList(generic.ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'index.html'

class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'

class Calendar(generic.DetailView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'calendar.html'

class Planoacao(generic.DetailView):
   model = Post
   template_name = 'planoacao.html'
```

This is my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^planoacao/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="planoacao.html")),
    url(r'calendar', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="calendar.html")),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls'), name="Blog"),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

How can I show a list of all posts in a different URL? xxx/planoacao.html ? Simply copying the html from index.html doesn´t work.

*Note that I don´t want to change the regular index.html post list, I just want to add a second post list page.*

Comment: Django does *not* come with any such thing as an out-of-the-box index.html.

Comment: However, the problem here is that your "planoacao" URL does not actually point at your Planoacao view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, as there is no Djangoview for dummies, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to show your `PostList` view at `/planoacao`, so in urls.py you can hook this path up to that view:

```
url(r'^planoacao/', PostList.as_view()),
```

Note that in Django there is no direct link between the path of a view and the template used. You can use any template with any path, all you have to do is define which template to use in the view.

Comment: I get an error:NameError: 'name PosList' is not defined

Comment: @ROCA you will need to import PostList in your urls.py